# MS SQL. Выбрать значения из диапазона

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы: Машины и Аренда. Необходимо выбрать машины которые одновременно были в аренде это Vesta и Granta. Они были в аренде одновременно с 8 по 14 января 2020 года.

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO Cars (ID, Code, Name)
VALUES (1, 'E01', 'Lada Vesta'),
(2, 'E02', 'Lada Calina'),
(3, 'E03', 'Lada Priora'),
(4, 'E03', 'Lada Granta'),
(5, 'E03', 'Lada Largus')


CREATE TABLE Rent (
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
ID_Cars INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Cars(ID),
DateBegin DATE NOT NULL,
DateEnd DATE NOT NULL
 )

INSERT INTO Rent (ID_Cars, DateBegin, DateEnd)
VALUES (1, '2019-08-10', '2019-09-01')
,(1, '2019-12-29', '2020-01-14')
,(2, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-15')
,(4, '2020-01-08', '2020-02-07')
,(5, '2020-06-07', '2020-07-12')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом простейшем варианте это

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c1.Name Name1, c2.Name Name2
FROM Rent r1
JOIN Rent r2 ON r1.DateBegin < r2.DateBegin AND r2.DateBegin < r1.DateEnd
JOIN Cars c1 ON c1.ID = r1.ID_Cars
JOIN Cars c2 ON c2.ID = r2.ID_Cars
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18955d1af6d80c529e6f15ebc5be6bf1

Comment: Где можно почитать литературу или посмотреть видео, чтобы понять как это делать?

Comment: @ДенисСоснин Вопрос непонятен. От слова "совсем"... делать ЧТО?

Comment: Я хочу понять как вы сделали это задание.

Comment: Я ищу в интернете похожие задания где выборка из диапазона идет, но не нахожу. Или это все с опытом приходит?

Comment: @ДенисСоснин *хочу понять как вы сделали это задание* Ааа... ну так это любой учебник по самым-самым основам языка SQL. *Или это все с опытом приходит?* Как по мне - голая логика. Просто надо представить, как это бы делалось, будь это тупо список на бумажке.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Здравствуйте. А как ток получается что как будто сравниваются 2 таблицы r1 и r2 . Это же одна таблица.

Comment: @ДенисСоснин Это две разные и независимые копии одной таблицы.